# Writing gremlin query using Perl and submiting it to JanusGraph

Tags: perl, gremlin, janusgraph

I want to automate some task for writing gremlin queries using Perl where I fetch data from my SQL system and building a gremlin query language and submitting it to  JanusGraph, the first part I am able to achieve with dbd::mysql and works good , but for gremlin https://docs.janusgraph.org/v0.4/basics/gremlin/
I didn't find any API on CPAN to do this, any idea how I can achieve this with Perl?

Comment: Looks like they don't support Perl. Maybe you can call a program in a supported language from your Perl program?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to fall back to REST/HTTP if you are using perl:

https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-http